# The following JavaScript code relate to Facebook

Tags: javascript

```
<!--Load scripts for Facebook scraper-->
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
  appId  : '154617751273927',
  status : true, // check login status
  cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});
};

 (function() {
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
e.async = true;
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

What is meant by the use of the word "scraper" in the comment? This looks like an async function, and it's http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

I am not sure what this al.js does. The result of that attached to the fb-root element.

What does this async function do and why is it called a "scraper"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have asked in your question-

`I am not sure what this al.js does`

Actually `all.js` is the `Facebook JavaScript SDK (Software Development Kit)` a JavaScript file with all common options.

`What does this async function do`

The `async` function loads the `SDK/all.js` file `asynchronously` which means it doesn't stop the page rendering during the loading of that file.

The SDK inserts elements into fb-root which expect to be positioned relative to the body or relative to an element close to the top of the page.

The function assigned to `window.fbAsyncInit` is run as soon as the SDK is loaded. Any code that you want to run after the SDK is loaded should be placed within this function and after the call to FB.init.

`Why is it called a scraper`

> Web scraping is closely related to web indexing, which indexes
> information on the web using a bot and is a universal technique
> adopted by most search engines. In contrast, web scraping focuses more
> on the transformation of unstructured data on the web, typically in
> HTML format, into structured data that can be stored and analyzed in a
> central local database or spreadsheet. Web scraping is also related to
> web automation, which simulates human browsing using computer
> software. Uses of web scraping include online price comparison,
> weather data monitoring, website change detection, research, web
> mashup and web data integration. [**Read More...**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)

`A little about faceBook __scraper__ from my understanding`

Actually, it can **scrape** data from the website (from your site, because you've used it/all.js) and can send that data to Facebook. Basically, one common example of this **scraping** is FaceBook `Like` button on web pages. When a user clicks on the faceBook Like button the **scraper** (all.js in this case) **scrape** some data from that site and sends those data to the faceBook and FaceBook posts those data to the user's profile but this is only one example. FaceBook **scraper** allows users to “Connect with Facebook” for an immersive and customized blog post or video experience. Users’ FB info such as name, age, location, profile picture, interests, etc., are scraped and weaved into a branded story.

[You can read more here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

On the web, some sites using `__scraper__`  also still data/content from good websites and posts into other websites by changing/modifying the original data. A few days ago I've found one of my SO answer on a different site and I really shocked. I've reported on meta [about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here/139839#139839), you may find it interesting.